# Word boundary with words starting or ending with special characters gives unexpected results

Tags: python, regex

Say I want to match the presence of the phrase `Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes}` in the phrase `test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} text`.

Using python `re` I could do this:

```
>>> search = re.escape('Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes}')
>>> match = 'test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} text'
>>> re.search(search, match)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 34), match='Sortes\\index[persons]{Sortes}'>
```

This works, but I want to avoid the search pattern `Sortes` to give a positive result on the phrase `test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} text`.

```
>>> re.search(re.escape('Sortes'), match)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 11), match='Sortes'>
```

So I use the `\b` pattern, like this:

```
search = r'\b' + re.escape('Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes}') + r'\b'
match = 'test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} text'
re.search(search, match)
```

Now, I don't get a match.

If the search pattern does not contain any of the characters `[]{}`, it works. E.g.:

```
>>> re.search(r'\b' + re.escape('Sortes\index') + r'\b', 'test Sortes\index test')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 17), match='Sortes\\index'>
```

Also, if I remove the final `r'\b'`, it also works:

```
re.search(r'\b' + re.escape('Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes}'), 'test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} test')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 34), match='Sortes\\index[persons]{Sortes}'>
```

Furthermore, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) says about `\b`

> Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string.

So I tried replacing the final `\b` with `(\W|$)`:

```
>>> re.search(r'\b' + re.escape('Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes}') + '(\W|$)', 'test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} test')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(5, 35), match='Sortes\\index[persons]{Sortes} '>
```

Lo and behold, it works!
What is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: `}`, the last character of your pattern is a non-word-character, as is the space following it. Thus there is no word boundary and no match. If the last character is `s`, it is a word-character, thus there is a word boundary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See what a word boundary matches:

A word boundary can occur in one of three positions:

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

In your pattern `}\b` only matches if there is a word char after `}` (a letter, digit or `_`).

When you use `(\W|$)` you require a non-word or end of string *explicitly*.

A solution is ***adaptive word boundaries***:

```
re.search(r'(?:(?!\w)|\b(?=\w)){}(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))'.format(re.escape('Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes}')), 'test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} test')
```

Or equivalent:

```
re.search(r'(?!\B\w){}(?<!\w\B)'.format(re.escape('Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes}')), 'test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} test')
```

Here, adaptive dynamic word boundaries are used that mean the following:

- `(?:(?!\w)|\b(?=\w))` (equal to `(?!\B\w)`) - a left-hand boundary, making sure the current position is at the word boundary if the next char is a word char, or no context restriction is applied if the next char is not a word char (**note** that you will need to use `(?:\B(?!\w)|\b(?=\w))` if you want to disallow a word char immediately on the left if the next char is not a word char)
- `(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))` (equal to `(?<!\w\B)`) - a right-hand boundary, making sure the current position is at the word boundary if the previous char is a word char, or no context restriction is applied if the previous char is not a word char (**note** that you will need to use `(?:(?<=\w)\b|\B(?<!\w))` if you want to disallow a word char immediately on the right if the preceding char is not a word char).

You might also consider using ***unambiguous word boundaries*** based on negative lookarounds in these cases:

```
re.search(r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'.format(re.escape('Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes}')), 'test Sortes\index[persons]{Sortes} test')
```

Here, `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if there is a word char immediately to the left of the current location, and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead will fail the match if there is a word char immediately to the right of the current location.

**Which to choose?** Adaptive word boundaries are more lenient compared to unambiguous word boundaries as the latter presume there must be no word chars on both ends of a match, while the former allow matching leading and trailing non-word chars in any context.

*Note*: It is easy to customize these lookaround patterns further (say, to only fail the match if there are *letters* around the pattern, use `[^\W\d_]` instead of `\w`, or if you only allow matches around whitespaces, use ***whitespace boundaries*** `(?<!\S)` / `(?!\S)` lookaround boundaries).

Comment: I like the suggestion about the negative look-arounds. This regex match is in a pretty hot part of my code, so I am worried about the performance of the match. Would that be a concern the with look-arounds?

Comment: @Stenskjaer `\b` is also a zero-width assertion, like any other lookaround. Since these lookaround patterns only contain single atoms, the overhead should not be too different from the one you already had with `\b`s. Well, you may set a quick performance test if you are worried, but this is the only correct regex way I can think of to solve the problem.

Comment: True! I just tested it myself. There is not (detectable) difference in performance. Thanks.

Comment: Adaptative word-boundaries can be written like that: `(?:(?!\w)|\b(?=\w))` => `(?!\B\w)` and `(?:(?<=\w)\b|(?<!\w))` => `(?<!\w\B)`

Comment: Also, I recorded a [*"Dynamic adaptive word boundaries"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbxagE2b68) YT video where I explain the constructs in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're running into:

`\b` lands on the boundary of `\w` and `\W`, but in the example that doesn't work. `'{Sortes}\b'` is the boundary between `\W` and `\W` because of the `'}'`, which doesn't match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, the ordinary set for `\w`.