# Matching a single word, in python 3 regex while using re.escape() as well

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I was trying to find a whole word using `regex` in Python 3. The best I can come up with is:

```
import re
search_string = 'CIS 22B : Intermediate Programming Methodologies in C++'

user_input = 'C++'
pattern = r'\b'+re.escape(user_input)

print(re.search(pattern,search_string))
```

Though, it has a flaw.. search would still be a success if this search string had the word `C++xyz` instead of `C++`. Which I don't want, I want it to match the word exactly.

There are answers for this problem on StackOverflow.. but none of them worked for me. Probably because they were for older version of Python.

Also, even for this code the method `search()` resulted an output.. but `match()` didn't. I have no idea why.

Please help!

Comment: for your last question, match matches at start of the string only.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180986/what-is-the-difference-between-re-search-and-re-match) for the difference between `match` and `search`. (Or, you know, read the documentation...)

Comment: You just tried wrong solutions. Use the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).

Comment: what do you mean with 'exactly'? C++ matches C++xyz exactly. You want C++ surrounded by spaces or nothing?

Comment: hint: `pattern = r'\b'+re.escape(user_input)+"(?=\W|$)"`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that worked! Thanks a lot :)