# Strange behaviour when searching for text with special chars using re.search and re.escape

Tags: python, regex

This is probably a very simple question which has already been answered but can't find the solution online.

I'm trying the following code to search for the word `foo` which works:

```
import re
haystack = 'bar foo, foo is a foobar'
needle = 'foo'
[m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(needle)), haystack)]
# [4, 9]
```

while the following, searching for `foo,` (note the comma) doesn't give what I would expect:

```
import re
haystack = 'bar foo, foo is a foobar'
needle = 'foo,'
[m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(needle)), haystack)]
# []
```

what's going on and how can I search for such strings with special characters (in general, not the specific case reported above)?

Thanks

Comment: Use `r'(?<!\w){}(?!\w)'`

Comment: The problem is in [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which should be placed near letters, not punctuation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970