# python regex replace redundant words with special characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to put together a regex expression that removes all occurring redundant words.

```
re.sub(r'\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})(\s{1,}\1\b)+', '\\1', "removing redundant redundant redundant")
>>> 'removing redundant'
```

Now I am stuck at the level where the redundant words start with special characters

```
re.sub(r'\b([#a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})(\s{1,}\1\b)+', '\\1', "removing red#undant red#undant red#undant")
>>> 'removing red#undant'

re.sub(r'\b([#a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})(\s{1,}\1\b)+', '\\1', "removing #redundant #redundant #redundant")
>>> 'removing #redundant #redundant #redundant'
```

I tried putting backslashes and many other combinations but nothing worked. I am sure there is something fundamental that i am not understanding or missing ...

thanks

Comment: That is because of `\b` whose meaning is context dependent. Replace with the unambiguous word boundaries, or precise their meaning with lookaheads.

Comment: what do you mean by unambiguous word boundaries ?

Comment: Read my answer.

Comment: Man if i understood i wouldn't be asking again :) regex is not my forté ...

Comment: See https://ideone.com/lo9uQT, `\b...\b` must be replaced with `(?<!\w)...(?!\w)`. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).

Comment: re.sub(r'((?<!\S)[$#a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})(\s{1,}\1\b)+', '\\1', "removing #redund$ant #redund$ant #redund$ant")

Comment: If your boundaries are whitespace ones, use `(?<!\S)...(?!\S)`.

Comment: thank you :) after reading your answer 100 times i understood it a bit :)

Comment: I suggest you should make a break for a half an hour, mediate a bit and re-read. All should be clear. Please drop  a comment if anything is not.