# Regex parsing chords

Tags: php, regex

I found this regex on another post in SO

```
\b(\(*[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb)*(?:\+|#|##|dim|sus|maj|min|aug|m|M|°|[0-9])*[\(]?[\d\/]*[\)]?(?:[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb)*(?:#|##|dim|sus|maj|min|aug|m|M|°|[0-9])*[\d\/]*)*\)*)\b
```

this regex works great when I use it with `preg_replace`, however when it's found the `A#` `B#` `C#` `D#` `E#` `F#` `G#` (not followed by `m` like `G#m`, in this case `G#m` is works just fine).

for example the following lyric will be highlighted `F` and `G#m` when I use the regex in `preg_replace($regex, '<span class="_c">$1</span>', $lyrics)`

```
F#
Angel eyes,
G#m
Why won’t you let me apologise?
```

[image: chord highlighted]

I am stucked, and not so good at regex. any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about music. What should happen? Is the issue that the `#` is matching as the non word boundary?

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [adaptive dynamic word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970):

```php
$lyrics = "F#\nAngel eyes,\nG#m\nWhy won’t you let me apologise?";
$regex = '/(?:\b(?=\w)|\B(?!\w))\(*\b[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb)*(?:\+|\#{1,2}|dim|sus|maj|min|aug|[mM°0-9])*\(?[\d\/]*\)?(?:[CDEFGAB](?:b|bb)*(?:\#{1,2}|dim|sus|maj|min|aug|[mM°0-9])*[\d\/]*)*\)*(?:\b(?<=\w)|\B(?<!\w))/';
echo preg_replace($regex, '<span class="_c">$1</span>', $lyrics)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFQoek/2).

The reason is that you matches can start or end with non-word chars, and `\b` word boundaries behave differently depending on their context.

Here, I suggest using adaptive dynamic word boundaries of Type 2:

- `(?:\b(?=\w)|\B(?!\w))` - a left-hand boundary, making sure the current position is at the word boundary if the next char is a word char (`\b(?=\w)`), or at a non-word boundary position if the next char is not a word char
- `(?:\b(?<=\w)|\B(?<!\w))` - a right-hand boundary, making sure the current position is at the word boundary if the previous char is a word char, or at a non-word boundary position if the previous char is not a word char.

You may also watch [this YT video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbxagE2b68) with more explanations of adaptive dynamic word boundaries and a Python demo.