# Splitting strings with words with any kind of characters inside as whole words

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to properly extract all terms from the text. Looks like when term is inside sentence and term contains `()` it's not splitted and regex couldn't find it.

I'm trying to properly split matches that contain `()`. So Instead of this:

`["What is API(Application Programming Interface) and how to use it?"]`

I'm trying to get this:

`["What is", "API(Application Programming Interface)", "and how to use it?"]`

JSON term is properly extracted and I'm getting this:

`["JSON", "is a Javascript Object Notation"]` so this is exactly what I want but in case of API I'm not getting this:

`["What is", "API(Application Programming Interface)", "and how to use it?"]`

I'm getting this and this is not what I want:

`["What is API(Application Programming Interface) and how to use it?"]`

```js
function getAllTextNodes(element) {
    let node;
    let nodes = [];
    let walk = document.createTreeWalker(element,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
    while (node = walk.nextNode()) nodes.push(node);
    return nodes;
  }

const allNodes = getAllTextNodes(document.getElementById("body"))

const terms = [
    {id: 1, definition: 'API stands for Application programming Interface', expression: 'API(Application Programming Interface)'},
    {id: 2, definition: 'JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation.', expression: 'JSON'}
]

const termMap = new Map(
      [...terms].sort((a, b) => b.expression.length - a.expression.length)
                .map(term => [term.expression.toLowerCase(), term])
    );

const regex = RegExp("\\b(" + Array.from(termMap.keys()).join("|") + ")\\b", "ig");

for (const node of allNodes) {
    const pieces = node.textContent.split(regex).filter(Boolean);
    console.log(pieces)
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
    <p>API(Application Programming Interface)</p>
    <p>What is API(Application Programming Interface) and how to use it?</p>
    <p>JSON is a Javascript Object Notation</p>
</div>
```

Comment: And the problem/question is? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: @Andreas sorry about that. So I created regex to match all the terms inside `#body` and properly split each node into array. So the only problem I have is how to properly split sentence when term is containing `()`

Comment: Escape the terms in your regex. And if you can have special chars at the start/end of the string, you can't use `\b` word boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your "words" can consist of non-word chars, you cannot rely on word boundaries. I would suggest switching to either unambiguous (`(?<!\w)`/`(?!\w)`) or [adaptive dynamic word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).

Besides, you need to [escape your terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) before using in the regex.

See below an example with adaptive word boundaries:

```js
function getAllTextNodes(element) {
    let node;
    let nodes = [];
    let walk = document.createTreeWalker(element,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
    while (node = walk.nextNode()) nodes.push(node);
    return nodes;
  }

const allNodes = getAllTextNodes(document.getElementById("body"))

const terms = [
    {id: 1, definition: 'API stands for Application programming Interface', expression: 'API(Application Programming Interface)'},
    {id: 2, definition: 'JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation.', expression: 'JSON'}
]

const termMap = new Map(
      [...terms].sort((a, b) => b.expression.length - a.expression.length)
                .map(term => [term.expression.toLowerCase(), term])
    );

const regex = RegExp("(?!\\B\\w)(" + Array.from(termMap.keys()).map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|") + ")(?<!\\w\\B)", "ig");

for (const node of allNodes) {
    const pieces = node.textContent.split(regex).filter(Boolean);
    console.log(pieces)
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
    <p>API(Application Programming Interface)</p>
    <p>What is API(Application Programming Interface) and how to use it?</p>
    <p>JSON is a Javascript Object Notation</p>
</div>
```

The regex is now `(?!\B\w)(api\(application programming interface\)|json)(?<!\w\B)` where

- `(?!\B\w)` - left-hand adaptive word boundary (with no context-checking if the following char is a non-word char)
- `(api\(application programming interface\)|json)` - Group 1 matching one of your terms (see escape special chars)
- `(?<!\w\B)` - right-hand adaptive word boundary (with no context-checking if the preceding char is a non-word char)