# Search for a word in a DataFrame column and ignore regex and substring

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching

I have a list of programming languages, and I want to check if a dataframe column contains said language (and create a new empty column with the language as the column name if it does). However, I'm running into 2 issues:

1. Some programming languages (like "`A++`") register as a regex, causing an error
2. I'm only trying to find matching *words*, but ***not*** substrings.

I've managed to work around my first problem (see minimal example) by parametrizing `str.contains` to ignore regex, but not the second.

How do I match specific words only (so for example, the programming language "Tea" shouldn't return True if the word is "Teapot"), without causing regex issues?

See the following for a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['A++ python', 'Teapot warmeR'],})
languages = ["Python", "R", "A++", "TEA"]

for lang in languages:
    if lang not in df.columns:
        if df['Text'].str.lower().str.contains(lang.lower(), regex=False).any():
            df[lang] = pd.Series(dtype='int')
```

This will however create a column for "R" and "Tea" too, which I do not want:

```
Text            Python R   A++ TEA
A++ python      NaN    NaN NaN NaN
Teapot warmeR   NaN    NaN NaN NaN
```

What I'd like to see is an exact word match:

```
Text           A++ Python 
A++ python     NaN NaN
Teapot warmeR  NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use adaptive word boundaries here:

```py
import re
for lang in languages:
    if lang not in df.columns:
        if df['Text'].str.lower().str.contains(fr'(?:(?!\w)|\b(?=\w)){re.escape(lang)}(?:\b(?<=\w)|(?<!\w))', regex=True, case=False).any():
            df[lang] = pd.Series(dtype='int')
```

Ouput:

```
>>> df
            Text  Python  A++
0     A++ python     NaN  NaN
1  Teapot warmeR     NaN  NaN
```

You can read more about these word boundary patterns in [Word boundary with words starting or ending with special characters gives unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970) and watch [this YT video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbxagE2b68) with more explanations and a Python demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution and some thoughts about this:

**A working solution if, as in your example, the strings are always separated by whitespaces in `Text`:**

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['A++ python', 'Teapot warmeR'],})
languages = ["Python", "R", "A++", "TEA"]

# Extracting column as list and convert to lower case
text_col = df['Text'].tolist()
text_col = [x.lower() for x in text_col]

# To lower case too
languages = [x.lower() for x in languages]

# Finding "whole words"
to_add = [lang for lang in languages for langs_list in text_col if lang in langs_list.split(" ")]

# Adding columns
for lang in to_add:
    df[lang] = pd.Series(dtype='int')

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
            Text  python  a++
0     A++ python     NaN  NaN
1  Teapot warmeR     NaN  NaN
```

**Thoughts:**

In fact this is an interesting multi-causal problem.

- 1st cause: "A++" ends with 2 plus signs which are regex special characters that need to be escaped
- 2nd: You need to find whole words, so we should use regex boudaries \b "as usual" but:
- 3rd: \b will match "Python", but \b won't work after the plus sign (a non-word character) of "A++" and the whitespace after it because \b is a zero width match that will match between a word character (\w) and a non-word character (\W) or between a word character and the start of end of string.
- 4th: We could replace the ending \b with \B, and the the regex will match "A++" because \B is \b negated. But this time, it will not match "Python" anymore and it will match "TEA"...

We could analyse this like that :

Here is the "final" (non-working) code and after that an explanation of the steps followed to write it:

```
for lang in languages:
    if lang not in df.columns:
        needle = re.escape(lang)
        needle = r'\b{}\B'.format(needle)
        if df['Text'].str.lower().str.contains(needle, case=False, regex=True).any():
            df[lang] = pd.Series(dtype='int')
```

- For clarity, we use `case=False` and remove `.str.lower()` and `lang.lower()`
- We set `regex=True` in order to use regex to match whole words. But as is, the regex will fail becasue "A++" needs to be escaped.
- We escape the strings with `needle = re.escape(lang)`. But now we get substrings: Pyton R, A++ and TEA.
- So we use word boundary `\b`: `needle = r'\b{}\b'.format(needle)`. But now we only get Python...
- So we use word boundary `\B` at the end: `needle = r'\b{}\B'.format(needle)`. Now, we get A++, but this does not match Python anymore and we also get TEA...

To conclude we can't use a simple regex that will work with all cases. BUT you can use a complex regex (**adaptive word boundaries** from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970) as in the answer of @Wiktor Stribiżew.

And, if, as in your example, the strings are always separated by whitespaces in `Text`, we could split on whitespaces and check if the whole words are in the resulting lists using `in` operator.