# Filter pandas column by list of phrases

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a string column of narratives. Each narrative is basically an essay. I want to take a subset of the df where certain phrases exist. The current method isn't working as intended. I'm filtering rows that don't contain the phrase exactly or just contains a subset of the phrase.

I've tried the following:

```
phrase = ['went to the store to buy an apple', 'corner of the street', 'fbi most wanted']
df['text'].str.contains(r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(phrase)), re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)
```

Not including an example because really just looking for a code review more than anything. The method above should look through the column text to see if those phrases exist, correct? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because you did not group the alternatives.

To do this right, you also coud sort phrases by length in the descending order, but here, in `contains`, it is not important:

```py
df['text'].str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(sorted(phrase, key=len, reverse=True))), case=False, regex=True)
```

I also recommend `case=False`  instead of `re.IGNORECASE`.

A foolproof version:

```py
df['text'].str.contains(r'(?!\B\w)(?:{})(?!\B\w)'.format('|'.join(sorted(map(re.escape, phrase), key=len, reverse=True))), case=False, regex=True)
```

where

- `phrases` are escaped for use in regex
- `phrases` are sorted
- `case=False` ensures case insensitive matching
- `(?!\B\w)` defines [adaptive word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45145626/3832970) and ensure correct whole word match
- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that groups patterns wthout capturing them (and causes no warnings in `Series.str.contains`).

Comment: Very informative. regex has always been a weak area for me so this helps tremendously, will definitely give it a try. I ended up looping through the list of words instead and need to run a quality check but will compare with your solution