# Pandas Matching Identical String

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have 2 dataframes: df_main and df_key. I am able to output the matching strings but no fully.

Key list has these strings: 'red', 'apple', 'red apple',

An example for the string in main df is: 'I want red apple'

The current output I have is: 'red', 'apple'

Below is the code I am using.

```
regex = r'\b({0})\b'.format('|'.join(df_key['column_name']))
df_main['column_name'] = df_main.Column_name.str.findall(regex, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
```

Ideally the output I want is 'red apple'

If not, outputting all the matches is fine: 'red', 'apple', 'red apple'

Comment: The 2 dataframes are taken from csv, and theres multiple columns so im just focusing on 1 column for each, hence the ['column_name']

Comment: Reverse your list so that you have the longest expression first

Comment: @Corralien i just tested it. simple yet crazy. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Do not reverse, sort. See [here how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70963489/3832970).