# How to test for word boundries, if the pattern starts or ends with punctuation?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I'm having a hard time testing whether a provided string (that likely starts with `!`) is surrounded by word boundries.

```js
// found in Mozilla's RegExp guide.
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

let msg = "a b c !test1 d e f";
let cmd = "!test1";

let re = new RegExp("\\b" + escapeRegExp(cmd) + "\\b");

console.log(`re: ${re.test(msg)}`);        // re: false
```

I assume this behaviour occurs, because punctuation itself is counted as a word boundry?

At least escaping the punctuation seems not to solve the problem. (I've tested a modified version of `escapeRegExp()` that includes `!`, same result.)

As an workaround I've used a version that splits `msg` at the white space and compares the elements with `cmd`. I'm not very happy with this solution as it breaks when `cmd` itself includes whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [adaptive dynamic word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970):

```js
// found in Mozilla's RegExp guide.
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

let msg = "a b c !test1 d e f";
let cmd = "!test1";

let re = new RegExp("(?!\\B\\w)" + escapeRegExp(cmd) + "(?<!\\w\\B)");
// console.log(re.source);// => (?!\B\w)!test1(?<!\w\B)
console.log(`re: ${re.test(msg)}`); 
// => re: true
```

The `(?!\B\w)!test1(?<!\w\B)` regex matches `!test1` and

- `(?!\B\w)` - checks if the next char is a word char, and if it is, a word boundary is required at the current location, else, the word boundary is not required
- `(?<!\w\B)` - checks if the previous char is a word char, and if it is, a word boundary is required at the current location, else, the word boundary is not required.

See some more details about [adaptive dynamic word boundaries in my YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngbxagE2b68).