# Word with special characters match via preg_match in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match, special-characters

Suppose I have a string like:

```
$str ="Model number is FM223-56/89.";
```

And I want match the model number only in this string via `preg_match`.
I am doing it like:

```
$model ="FM223-56/89.";

$pattern = '/\b'.$model.'\b/';
echo preg_match($pattern, $str);
```

But no luck, I want to search word that can have `.-,'/"` in it, Is it possible to search via `preg_match`?

There is no fixed pattern.

Comment: Try quoting the string first: `'/\b'.preg_quote($model).'\b/';` - That escapes any characters that has special meaning in regex. However, if you just want to check if a string occurs in another string, you don't need regex. In PHP 8, you can use [str_contains()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) and pre PHP 8, you can use [strstr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. Believe it or not `.` is not a word boundary `\b`
2. You are using `/` as a delimiter but there is a `/` in your pattern

So either use a different delimiter:

```
$pattern = "~\b".$model."~";
```

Or better, escape the variable and specify your delimiter:

```
$pattern = '/'.preg_quote($model, '/').'/';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [*adaptive dynamic word boundaries*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970), i.e. only apply word boundaries if the neighboring chars are word chars:

```php
$str ="Model number is FM223-56/89.";
$model ="FM223-56/89.";
$pattern = '/(?!\B\w)' . preg_quote($model, '/') . '(?<!\w\B)/';
echo preg_match($pattern, $str); // => 1
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ZhopS).

- `(?!\B\w)` - checks if the next char is a word char, and if it is, a word boundary is required at the current location, else, the word boundary is not required
- `(?<!\w\B)` - checks if the previous char is a word char, and if it is, a word boundary is required at the current location, else, the word boundary is not required.

Note the `preg_quote($model, '/')` part: it escapes all special chars in the `$model` string and also the `/` char that is used as a regex delimiter char.