# C# Regex whitespace between capturing groups

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

So basically, my input string is some kind of text containing keywords that I want to match, provided that:

1. each keyword may have whitespace/non-word chars pre/appended, or none `(|\s\W)`
2. there must be exactly one non-word/whtiespace char seperating multiple keywords, or keyword is at begining/end of line
3. Keyword simply ocurring as a substring does not count, e.g. `bar` does not match `foobarbaz`

E.g.:

```
input:    "#foo barbazboo tree car"
keywords: {"foo", "bar", "baz", "boo", "tree", "car"}
```

I am dynamically generating a Regex in C# using a enumerable of keywords and a string-builder

```
StringBuilder sb = new();
foreach (var kwd in keywords)
{
   sb.Append($"((|[\\s\\W]){kwd}([\\s\\W]|))|");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // last '|'
_regex = new Regex(sb.ToString(), RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Testing this pattern on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com), given input matches all keywords. However, I do not want `{bar, baz, boo}` included, since there is no whitespace between each keyword.
Ideally, I'd want my regex to only match `{foo, tree, car}`.

Modifying my pattern like `(( |[\s\W])kwd([\s\W]| ))` causes `{bar, baz, boo}` not to be included, but produces bogus on `{tree, car}`, since for that case there must be at least two spaces between keywords.

How do I specify "there may be only one whitespace seperating two keywords", or, to put it differently, "half a whitespace is ok", preserving the ability to create the regex dynamically?

Comment: This looks too messy and convoluted. Are you trying to match the keywords as whole words? `_regex = new Regex($@"\b(?:{string.Join("|", keywords.Select(Regex.Escape))})\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: One question though: can the `keywords` start/end with non-word chars?

Comment: Yes, but at most one. So `{"#foo%", "#foo", "foo%"}` matches keyword `foo`

Comment: Well, I meant if the `keywords` can start/end with a non-word char, not the input text.

Comment: Oh, yeah, they could. They may include space-chars as well.

Comment: Ok, that means you cannot use `\b` here.

Comment: But only for whitespaces in a keyword, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Can the keywords look like `keywords: {"$foo", "^bar^", "[baz]", "(boo)", "tree+", "+car"}`?

Comment: Okay, I misread your question again. No, they cant; At most they'd look like `{"foo bar", "tree car"}`.

Comment: Aha, so `\b` will work, but you need to sort the keywords before putting them into the pattern.

Comment: Alphabetically? How come?

Comment: I posted the two solutions, the first one is for you, the second one is a generic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to build the

```cs
var pattern = $@"\b(?:{string.Join("|", keywords.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).Select(Regex.Escape))})\b";
_regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Here, you are getting the longer keywords before shorter ones, so, if you have `foo`, `bar` and `foo bar`, the pattern will look like `\b(?:foo\ bar|foo|bar)\b` and will match `foo bar`, and not `foo` and `bar` once there is such a match.

In case your keywords can look like `keywords: {"$foo", "^bar^", "[baz]", "(boo)", "tree+", "+car"}`, i.e. they can have special chars at the start/end of the keyword,  you can use

```cs
_regex = new Regex($@"(?!\B\w)(?:{string.Join("|", keywords.Select(Regex.Escape))})(?<!\w\B)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The `$@"(?!\B\w)(?:{string.Join("|", keywords.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).Select(Regex.Escape))})(?<!\w\B)"` is an interpolated verbatim string literal that contains

- `(?!\B\w)` - left-hand [adaptive dynamic word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970)
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `{string.Join("|", keywords.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).Select(Regex.Escape))}` - sorts the keywords by lenght in descending order, escapes them and joins with `|`
- `)`  - end of the group
- `(?<!\w\B)` - right-hand adaptive dynamic word boundary.