# Search and replace method using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, regexp-replace

I'm looking for a regular expression to implement a search and replace method which identifies strings like "/Sample Text:" in a longer text (e.g. "This is a /Sample Text: in a sentence"), where 'Match whole word' and/or 'Match case' can be specified. I'm new to regular expressions. Thank you very much.

I tried something like below, but it is not what I expect:

```
var text = "This is a /Sample Text: in a sentence";
var oldValue = "/Sample Text:";
var newValue = "sample text";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, $"\\b{oldValue}{(char.IsPunctuation(newValue[newValue.Length - 1]) ? "(?!\\" + newValue[newValue.Length - 1] + ")" : string.Empty)}", newValue, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the "words" can contain any special characters anywhere inside the "word". In this case, you need to

- Escape the `oldValue` "words"
- Use dynamic [adaptive word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).

See an [example C# demo](https://ideone.com/nS7c8K):

```cs
var text = "This is a /Sample Text: in a sentence";
var oldValue = "/Sample Text:";
var newValue = "sample text";
var matchCase = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
var result = Regex.Replace(text, $@"(?!\B\w){Regex.Escape(oldValue)}(?<!\w\B)", newValue, matchCase);
```

The `result` value is `This is a sample text in a sentence`.

The `(?!\B\w){Regex.Escape(oldValue)}(?<!\w\B)` means

- `(?!\B\w)` - a position that is preceded with a word boundary only if the following char is a word char
- `{Regex.Escape(oldValue)}` - an interpolated string variable that is an escaped value of `oldValue`
- `(?<!\w\B)` - a position that is followed with a word boundary only if the preceding char is a word char.

Comment: Thanks. Does the code also work if oldValue looks like "/Sample: Text!" ? What about 'Match whole word' and/or 'Match case' options? Thanks.

Comment: @mca You can add the conditions yourself, it is basic code not related to regex already. Also, the `matchCase` is already in the code.