# Match standalone words in string in DataFrame column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "M1", "M2", "M3"], 
                  "Requirements": ["3 meters|2/3 meters|3.5 meters",
                                   "3 meters",
                                   "3/5 meters|3 meters",
                                   "2/3 meters",
                                   "steel|g1_steel",
                                   "steel",
                                   "g1_steel"]})
```

***dataframe df***

```
  Name                    Requirements
0   D1  3 meters|2/3 meters|3.5 meters
1   D2                        3 meters
2   D3             3/5 meters|3 meters
3   D4                      2/3 meters
4   M1                  steel|g1_steel
5   M2                           steel
6   M3                        g1_steel
```

I have a list of words `req_list = ['3 meters', 'steel']` and I am trying to extract rows from `df` where the strings in column `Requirements` contain standalone words that are from `req_list`. This is what I have done:

***This one prints just D2 and M2***

```
df[df.Requirements.apply(lambda x: any(len(x.replace(y, '')) == 0 for y in req_list))]
```

***This one prints all rows***

```
df[df['Requirements'].str.contains(fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(req_list)})\b")]
```

My desired result is as follows:

```
  Name                    Requirements
0   D1  3 meters|2/3 meters|3.5 meters
1   D2                        3 meters
2   D3             3/5 meters|3 meters
4   M1                  steel|g1_steel
5   M2                           steel
```

In this desired output, D4 and M3 are eliminated because they do not have words from `req_list` as standalone strings. Is there any way to achieve this preferably in an one-liner without using custom functions?

**EDIT**

The strings in the column `Requirements` can come in any pattern such as:

```
    Name                    Requirements
0   D1    3 meters|2/3 meters|3.5 meters
1   D2                          3 meters
2   D3               3/5 meters|3 meters
3   D4                        2/3 meters
4   D5                       3::3 meters # New pattern which needs to be eliminated
5   D6                        3.3 meters # New pattern which needs to be eliminated
6   D7                        3?3 meters # New pattern which needs to be eliminated
7   M1                    steel|g1_steel
8   M2                             steel
9   M3                          g1_steel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to make sure you do not match `3 meters` that is preceded with a digit + `/`, you may add a `(?<!\d/)` negative lookbehind after the intial word boundary:

```py
df[df['Requirements'].str.contains(fr"\b(?<!\d/)(?:{'|'.join(req_list)})\b")]
```

Output:

```
  Name                    Requirements
0   D1  3 meters|2/3 meters|3.5 meters
1   D2                        3 meters
2   D3             3/5 meters|3 meters
4   M1                  steel|g1_steel
5   M2                           steel
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rjscCL/1).

**Notes**

- Since `req_list` contains *phrases* (mutiword strings) you might have to sort the items by length in the descending order before joining with the `|` *OR* operator, so you'd better use `fr"\b(?<!\d/)(?:{'|'.join(sorted(req_list, key=len, reverse=True))})\b"` as regex
- If the `req_list` ever contains items with special chars you should also use [adaptive dynamic word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970), i.e. `fr"(?!\B\w)(?<!\d/)(?:{'|'.join(sorted(map(re.escape, req_list), key=len, reverse=True))})(?<!\w\B)"`.

Comment: Good one! Thumbs up!!!

Comment: Thank you so much for this extremely crisp and clear solution! I am so sorry but I forgot to mention that the strings in `Requirements` column can come in any pattern which I have added as an edit in question.

Comment: @Animeartist Try `\b(?<!\d[^\w\s])(?<!\d[^\w\s][^\w\s])(?:3 meters|steel)\b`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rjscCL/2).

Comment: It works for most cases but fails for cases like `.3 meters`

Comment: @Animeartist What do you consider to be the match start?

Comment: Match start could be anything like `.3 meters`, `d-3 meters` and so on

Comment: @Animeartist No, I mean the left-hand match boundary. I have had a glance, and now think you want to only start a match 1) at the start of string, 2) after a `|` char. So, try `\b(?<![^\s|])(?:3 meters|steel)\b`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rjscCL/3).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way to do it

```
def chk(row):
    for r in row:
        if r.strip() in req_list:
            return True
    return False

df[df.assign(lst = df['Requirements'].str.split('|'))['lst'].apply(chk) == True]
```

```
    Name    Requirements
0   D1      3 meters|2/3 meters|3.5 meters
1   D2      3 meters
2   D3      3/5 meters|3 meters
4   M1      steel|g1_steel
5   M2      steel
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is indeed a very nice solution that covers all usecases but I was hoping for it to be an one-liner since I am refactoring the codebase and can't make too many changes