# Question about matching RE in a complicated form

Tags: python, regex, python-re, regex-greedy

How can I match a word using RE in the following format:
Letter number Alphanumeric dot(.) Alphanumeric{0-4}

Examples:

```
A24.L
A2F.L9
A2F.LG4
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
answer=re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]\d\w\.\w{0-4})
```

Comment: “*is it correct?*” I’m not understanding, have you not tested it yet? Why not?

Comment: Search "test regex" for sites that can help you with this. Or just try it out in Python. There's no need for a question as you've posed it.

Comment: A common beginner error is forgetting word boundaries. Your regex will match any substring in a longer string; I'm guessing that's not what you want. For example, it will pick out "a24.exam" from "ba24.example.com"

Comment: `0-4` should be `0,4`

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `re.findall`, I assume you are looking for partial matches inside longer text. Bearing that in mind, you need to fix the following:

- `\w` matches not only alphanumeric, but also a `_` char
- `{0-4}` is not a valid limiting ("range", or "interval") quantifier, it has a `{min,max}` syntax (note that the `min` value should not be omitted, although some regex engines allow that with `0` value used as default, but there are regex engines that either do not support or that do not work correctly with this omitting)
- In Python 3, `\d` matches any Unicode digit (like `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈၉႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘႙០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៩᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᥏᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧙᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᭙᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷᮸᮹᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱉᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘᱙꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꣙꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꤉꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꩙０１２３４５６７８９`), so you probably want to use `(?a)` inline modifier (to only match ASCII digits) or an explicit `[0-9]`.

So, you can use

```py
answer=re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\b', text)
```

if the alphanumeric after `.` is obligatory, and the following if the match can end in a dot:

```py
answer=re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\.[A-Za-z0-9]{0,4}(?<!\w\B)', text)
```

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]` - a letter
- `[0-9]` - an ASCII digit
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` - an ASCII alphanumeric
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{1,4}\b` - one to four alphanumeric chars at the word boundary.

The second regex does not contain a word boundary at the end since the match is supposed to be able to end in a `.` (that is not a word char). The `(?<!\w\B)` is a right-hand [dynamic word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970) that only requires a non-word char or end position if the preceding char is a word char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jIRxbJ/1).