# Python re.sub always returns the original string value and ignores given pattern

Tags: python, regex

**My code below**

```
old = """
B07K6VMVL5
B071XQ6H38
B0B7F6Q9BH
B082KTHRBT
B0B78CWZ91
B09T8TJ65B
B09K55Z433
"""
duplicate = """
B0B78CWZ91
B09T8TJ65B
B09K55Z433
"""
final = re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(duplicate),"",old)
print(final)
```

**The final always prints the old variable values.I want the duplicate values to be removed in the old variable**

Comment: First of all, why not `old.replace(duplicate,'')`? Next, you need to `strip` the `duplicate` - `re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(duplicate.strip()),"",old)`, or at least `rstrip` it as there is no word boundary between a newline and end of string.

Comment: To further spell out what @Wiktor is saying, the final `\b` does not match because there is no word boundary after the final newline.

Comment: I have formatted the code as follows. `final = re.sub(r"{}".format(duplicate),"",old)
  print(final)` . Got the same old variable value. `old.replace(duplicate,'')` also prints old value only

Comment: And now, do you have any issues? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually I need to get duplicate variable as an input  from an user and checks in with old variable (which is a already stored data) to remove the duplicates.

Comment: So does the top comment solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The block string should not start/end in a new line since it will introduce a `\n` character. Try with

```
old = """B07K6VMVL5
B071XQ6H38
B0B7F6Q9BH
B082KTHRBT
B0B78CWZ91 #    <-
B09T8TJ65B #    <-
B09K55Z433""" # <-

duplicate = """B0B78CWZ91
B09T8TJ65B
B09K55Z433"""
```

and the result will not equal to the `old`.

Output

```
B07K6VMVL5
B071XQ6H38
B0B7F6Q9BH
B082KTHRBT
```

---

Alternatively use the block string like this

```
"""\
B0B78CWZ91
B09T8TJ65B
B09K55Z433\
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use

```py
final = re.sub(r"(?!\B\w){}(?<!\w\B)".format(re.escape(duplicate.strip())),"",old)
```

Note several things here:

- `duplicate.strip()` - the whitespaces on both ends may prevent from matching, so `strip()` removes them from the `duplicates`
- `re.escape(...)` - if there are special chars they are properly escaped with `re.escape`
- `(?!\B\w)` and `(?<!\w\B)` are [dynamic adaptive word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45145626/3832970). They provide proper matching at word boundaries if required.