# Finding and replacing match for exact abbreviations using Regex in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a `REPLACEMENTS` dictionary whose keys are the strings that I want to find **exactly**. Then I want to replace them with their corresponding dictionary values.

For example,

```
REPLACEMENTS = dict([('max.' , ' maximum '),
                     ('inkl.' , ' inklusive '),
                     ('z.b.' , ' zum beispiel '),
                     ('ggf.', ' gegebenfalls ')])

sample_input_text = "Hallo, ggf ggf. max z.b. alpha z.b beta ca. 25 cm ca inkl. inkl. inkl"
```

**Expected output**

```
"Hallo, ggf  gegebenfalls max zum beispiel alpha z.b beta circa 25 cm ca inklusive inklusive inkl"`
```

As you can notice, I do not want to replace words like `ggf`, `ca`, and `inkl` because they don't match exactly with the dictionary keys `ggf.`, `ca.`, and `inkl.` due to the missing dot.

**My Attempt:**

As you can see below, I am getting matches like `'ggf ', 'max '` and `'z.b '` that do not match exactly with the dictionary keys. These partial matches are then replaced by a blank character when I use `re.sub`.

```
import re

REPLACEMENTS = dict([('max.' , ' maximum '),
                     ('inkl.' , ' inklusive '),
                     ('z.b.' , ' zum beispiel '),
                     ('ggf.', ' gegebenfalls ')])

sample_input_text = "Hallo, ggf ggf. max z.b. alpha z.b beta ca. 25 cm ca inkl. inkl. inkl"

joined = '|'.join(REPLACEMENTS.keys())

print(re.findall(joined, sample_input_text))

>> ['ggf ', 'ggf.', 'max ', 'z.b.', 'z.b ', 'inkl.', 'inkl.']

pattern = re.compile(joined)

output_text = pattern.sub(lambda m: REPLACEMENTS.get(m.group()), sample_input_text)
print(output_text)

>> 'Hallo,  gegebenfalls  zum beispiel  alpha beta ca. 25 cm ca  inklusive   inklusive  inkl'
```

What would be the regex pattern for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed code:

```py
import re
REPLACEMENTS = dict([('max.' , ' maximum '),
                     ('inkl.' , ' inklusive '),
                     ('z.b.' , ' zum beispiel '),
                     ('ggf.', ' gegebenfalls '),
                     ('ca.' , ' circa ')])

sample_input_text = "Hallo, ggf ggf. max z.b. alpha z.b beta ca. 25 cm ca inkl. inkl. inkl"
joined = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, REPLACEMENTS.keys())) + r')(?!\B\w)'
print(re.findall(joined, sample_input_text))

pattern = re.compile(joined)
output_text = pattern.sub(lambda m: REPLACEMENTS.get(m.group()), sample_input_text)
print(output_text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fXQ3xK). Output:

```
Hallo, ggf  gegebenfalls  max  zum beispiel  alpha z.b beta  circa  25 cm ca  inklusive   inklusive  inkl
```

**NOTE**:

- To cater for `circa`, I added `('ca.' , ' circa ')` to the `REPLACEMENTS` dictionary
- The pattern is built using `r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, REPLACEMENTS.keys())) + r')(?!\B\w)'`:

  - `\b` at the start matches a word boundary
  - `map(re.escape, REPLACEMENTS.keys())` escapes each key to be used inside a regex (the dots need escaping to match literal dots)
  - As the keys end with a `.` (and I suppose there can be other abbreviations that end with word chars) you cannot rely on `\b`, but you can use [adaptive word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970). `(?!\B\w)` makes sure there is a word boundary if the key found ends with a word char.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for your answer. Could you please explain the `(?:` and `?!` are used for at the start and the end of the pattern?

Comment: @Sheldore `(?:...)`  is a non-capturing group, as we need to apply word boundaries to all the keywords. And `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead.